# Flask - Externally Visible Dev Server

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

The [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) describe an externally visible server that allows users on your network to access your running app. The docs seem to assume a level of understanding that I don't possess and I can't figure out how to make it work.

I've adjusted my `app.run()` method, passing it the `host='0.0.0.0'` argument, as instructed in the docs.

How does a user in my network access my app? What address do they visit? Do other settings need to be configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to access it by going to: `0.0.0.0:port`.

Someone on your network can access it by going to `your-local-ip:port`.

Depending on your system, there is a way of finding your local IP address, but it should look something like `192.168.X.X`.

Comment: If you're on a *nix system, you can run "ifconfig" to get your network IP; on Windows, "ipconfig" will list it.