# Unable to access Flask web app from php curl

Tags: php, python, curl, flask, web-development-server

I have a Flask app, with a basic function, where I have exposed app.run() to a public ip, so that it is accessible from an external server;[ using [Flask - Externally Visible Dev Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793115/flask-externally-visible-dev-server) ]

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080)
```

The curl request I have written in my php code is:

```
$signed_url = "http://my-ip-address:8080/";
$ch = curl_init($signed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data= curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

I can do a curl request :

```
curl http://my-ip-address:8080/
```

from command line. However, when the curl request is embedded within my PHP code, it gives me an error "Connection refused".

Kindly help!

Comment: Is cURL and your PHP code both tested on the same machine, or is the PHP code on some other server?

Comment: On another server. The command line curl request is through my teammate's local machine, and the php code request from her web server ( Cpanel).

Comment: what about getting curl error with http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: @tanaydin, yes we did try it. It gives "Error 7: Connection refused" error.

Comment: also check for selinux. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7190494/1157106

Answer (score 1):

If the PHP code is on another server, but your command line cURL request is on the same server, then you aren't comparing apples to apples.

Two things that might be wrong:

1. Your Flask server has a firewall that doesn't allow external connections.
2. You are connecting using an private network IP address rather than a public IP address.

For now your PHP code looks correct, so I would narrow down the problem a little bit. Ignore that PHP code and try to connect using cURL on the command line from the same server you are running your PHP code on.

Comment: Hi @Martin, Thanks so much for the reply! However, the main issue was that PHP curl command did not allow the port number to be specified. Hence, while it is not 'ideal', I bound the port to 80, due to which only the IP Address could be specified which took care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to set your port with curl options like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
```

so your signed url will be:

```
$signed_url = "http://my-ip-address";
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for my work and worked :)

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:5000/spmi/api/1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"teks_analysis\":\"tidak ada skor nol\"}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

the key is CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS